# What happens when a quarry mines a chest?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-buildcraft

I have a quarry mining above an abandoned mine. There's a good chance eventually the quarry will mine a chest block. Will the quarry suck up the chest with its contents, or just the chest?

Comment: I am not familiar with ftb, but at some time vanilla Minecraft start having Minecart with Chest instead of normal chests in abandoned mineshafts. Does this matter?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The quarry breaks open the chest and then picks up the items on the ground as it passes over them. It's the same way for beehives, if you have those in your world.

Comment: could we get a source for this just to confirm?

Comment: @wonton I'll find something more recent or make my own later, but [here](http://youtu.be/DS1H4OY0yyg) is a video showing quarry vs turtles, and at [2:35](http://youtu.be/DS1H4OY0yyg?t=2m35s) you see the chest with wool in it, and at [10:40](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DS1H4OY0yyg&feature=youtu.be&t=10m40s) you see the results.

Comment: As for the bees, I only have the stacks of them in my ME as proof. Interesting note: if you get a chicken stuck in your quarry, it'll pick up the eggs as it goes down.

Comment: What a quarry is is a machine that breaks any blocks in sight and then sucks it up.